# moderator tools

Tags: support

I want to know what tools do the moderators have ?
 the goal of this question is to aid a university project in which we think of a programming idea and implement a senior product, we're thinking of something like the tools needed to moderate a website, I can't tell the details for personal reasons.
So how do moderators do their job ? how do they maintain  and in particular how does the website help them ?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: That's classified. (I'm kidding, btw. iKIsR could you post that as the answer?)

Comment: I think you will get better answers if you ask on http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @iKlsR is there a way to migrate it ?